# Word meaning "with light shining behind"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Say, you are in a P.E. storeroom. Someone opens the door. So the light comes from behind the person, making the front part black. How do you call this physical phenomena (in colloquial words)?

Example sentence:

> Fumiko thought the P.E. storeroom was the best place to hide. At least until the door creaked open and a __ figure.

Comment: ... what happened to Fumiko?  You can't just leave us hanging!

Comment: @Andrew Fumiko was in the P.E storeroom to hide from her crush. Because she farts every time she's face to face with the guy she likes. In the end, the guy finds her there and things blow up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is either [backlit](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/backlit) or [silhouetted](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/silhouetted).